# Change div background-url by clicking

Tags: html, background, repeat

So, I got this div:

```
<div id="pictures" style="
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px; left: 0;
width: 100%;
background-image: url(inhalt/lan7071.jpg);
background-position: bottom;
 background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
z-index: 1;
height: -moz-calc(100% - 170px);
height: -webkit-calc(100% - 170px);
height: -o-calc(100% - 170px);"
></div>
```

Klicking on text in a table someplace else on the same .htm I want to change the background url of this div:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td ><a onclick="document.getElementById('pictures').style.background='url(content/image2.jpg)'">Image 2<a></td>
      <td ><a onclick="document.getElementById('pictures').style.background='url(content/image3.jpg)'">Image3<a></td>

    </tr>
  </table>
```

After clicking on "image 2" the background indeed is changed, but also repeated on the entire div, I guess the "    background-size: contain;    background-repeat: no-repeat;" are ignored.

Is there any small, easy jQuery way to simpyl change the background URL of another div after clicking on another? I would also like the new background to retain the specifications from the earlier one like no-repeat, size-contain, etc ...

I like the idea of being able to just add a short js code before or after each link and having a js-function someplace else on the site.

jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/R7gEH/

Thanks a lot & merry christmas!

Answer (score 1):

when you change backgroud property you overwrite everything related to background. Just set background-image. For javascript it will be `backgroundImage`.

Using jquery

```
$("#pictures").css("background-image", "new url");
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before. Both

<a onclick="document.getElementById('pictures').style.background-image='url(content/image2.jpg)'">Image 2<a>

and

<a onclick="document.getElementById('pictures').style.background-url='url(content/image2.jpg)'">Image 2<a>

don't work at all unfortunately. ... does jQuery help here?

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

----CSS-----------

```
.background-change{
    //set new property of image with !important 
}
```

------jQuery -------

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('background-change') ;
});
```

this will add the new property class. Also remove it when it is not needed.(using removeClass() function)

Comment: Thanks Riad ... isn't that too complicated when I have about 200pictures I want to show in the div?
I added a jfiddle for this problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/R7gEH/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys ... I did the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/8m7VB/

```
<div id="bilder" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%;
height: -moz-calc(100% - 170px); height: -webkit-calc(100% - 170px); height: -o-calc(100% - 170px);

background: url(https://www.google.de/logos/doodles/2013/holiday-series-2013-2-5173241802915840-hp.png) center bottom no-repeat; background-size: contain; z-index: 1;"></div>
<a onclick="document.getElementById('bilder').style.background='url(https://www.google.de/logos/doodles/2013/holiday-series-2013-2-5173241802915840-hp.png) center bottom no-repeat'">google<a>
<a onclick="document.getElementById('bilder').style.background='url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9G
```